# ASP.NET Web Forms URL Rewriting capability

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a very simple question, rather I am just curious.

I have about 2000 pages of the url format `somewebsite.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=223` . This particular url has a page title as 'Walking sticks for elders made from durable steel'.

Can I use URL Rewriting to convert this to a url like `somewebsite.com/walking-stick-for-elders` ? Also will I have do it dynamically for 2000 pages or is there any expression that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some thing which uniquely indentifies URLs just like Stackoverflow does it.

[ASP.NET Web Forms URL Rewriting capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787153/asp-net-web-forms-url-rewriting-capability)

See this question URL - Where from URL you get its for question then there is a question id and then description. I suggest you do the same.

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or higher version then you can do that type of URL routing very easily.

Like from this URL - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

There is also a asp.net friendly URL package form where you can write URls.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If each product name is unique and stored inside the database you can easily route each SEO friendly URL to productID without manually inputing a new route in the Routing table.